# php tokenisation

Tags: php, sql

I have a string of characters separated by many hashes (#). I need to get the individual words in between the hashes on php. here's what my code looks like:

```
$sql = "SELECT attribute_type.at_name,attribute_type.at_id FROM attribute_type 
WHERE attribute_type.prodType_id = $pt_id 
AND attribute_type.at_id NOT IN (SELECT at_id 
                                 FROM attribute_type 
                                 WHERE attribute_type.at_name = 'Product')";

        while($items. strpos("#")>0){
            // add the selected AT in every loop to be excluded
            // .
            // here tokens from $items are stored individually in 
            // $selectedAT (whose value changes in every loop/cycle)
            //
            // add to the current sql statement the values $at_id and $searchparam
            $sql = $sql .  "AND attribute_type.at_id NOT IN 
                           (SELECT at_id FROM attribute_type 
                            WHERE attribute_type.at_name = '$selectedAT')";
        }

        $dbcon = new DatabaseManager();
        $rs = $dbcon->runQuery($sql);
```

Answer (score 5):

`explode` creates an array by splitting a string on a given token

```
$words = explode("#", $items);
```

Now if you need to take these words you extracted from the string and use them to compare to some column in a SQL query...

```
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE column IN ('" . implode("', '", $words) . "')";
```

You should not need to build a query in a loop as you are doing once you have the words in an array.

Even if you did want to do it that way, you don't want to create a subquery for every word when you could just OR the words together in one subquery.

Comment: split is deprecated. It's better to use explode :)

Comment: Split has been deprecated. Use explode() instead.

Comment: You should not use `split`, it's deprecated. Try `explode`.

Comment: Changed before ya even wrote that.

Comment: Don't forget to make sure the data is actually safe to build a query from before actually running it!  $words = array_map ('mysql_real_escape_string', $words) for example.  You don't want to end up like Bobby Tables

Comment: Dan Grossman -  thanks for your contribution, however i have not succeeded in implementing the sql. 
I tried this: SELECT attribute_type.at_id FROM attribute_type WHERE attribute_type.at_name =  '" . implode(" ', ' ", $selectedAT) . " ') but it aint working :(

Comment: @Onks That's not valid SQL. You can't compare a column to a list of values with an equals sign.

Comment: @Dan Grossm PERFECT!!!. Its now working!! Problem solved..am all smiles :) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try [`strtok`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php). Example paste:

```
$string = "This is\tan example\nstring";

$tok = strtok($string, " \n\t");

while ($tok !== false) {
    echo "Word=$tok<br />";
    $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
}
```

Comment: Pretty much overkill if he can just explode() it. Even though your solution is most likely more memory-efficient if it's a huge string with tons of tokens.

Comment: @Thief Agreed. This answer also leans a bit towards *"you'd have found that if you'd have searched the manual"* though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use split <strike>as suggested in another answer</strike> (which has now been updated). It uses old POSIX regulat expressions and it's deprecated.

To split a string, use `$words = explode('#', $items);` which does not use a regular expression but a plain string.

Docref: http://php.net/explode

Comment: 'explode' nice...dint know that was possible